# Rename/translate multiple files on Mac

Tags: macos, rename, translate

I have a lot of files with names in one language and I need to rename them all to another one.
Is there any script for this? (preferably on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. We can do it with [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) CLI utility.

Install it with `brew install translate-shell`

Then run next script in your folder:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
    sleep 5
    mv -i "$i" "$(echo ${i%.txt} | trans -b nl:en).txt"; 
done
```

translate-shell makes a call to Google Translate server to do translation

`sleep 5` is needed to avoid being blocked by Google's server for too many requests in a second

`trans` is actual translate command

`-b` stands for "brief", as we don't need verbose output

`nl:en` are the source and destination languages